# Access Parent object PHP

Tags: php

I have class that extends another class.

```
class TWITTER_FOLLOWERS extends TWITTER_BOT
```

in **TWITTER_FOLLOWERS** i want to acces the **db** object from **TWITTER_BOT**
but i get just an error

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all_array() on a non-object in /var/www/bot/inc/TWITTER_FOLLOWERS.php on line 163**

On line 163 i have this code

```
$results = $this->db->fetch_all_array($q);
```

How can i access the parent object db ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't instantiated the $db variable in the parent class. Are you using a `__construct()` function in your subclass? Don't forget to call `parent::__construct()` in there so the function isn't "overwritten". Also, is $db a `protected` or `public` variable? It'll need to be one of the two for a subclass to be able to access it. We'll need to see more code to dig deeper.

Comment: that is correct after calling parent::__constrictor() it fixed the error thanks

Answer (score 2):

did you run the parent constructor?  this looks like the subclass doesn't bother initializing properly (by calling the parent constructor).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not sure what you exactly want. But my guess would be that you are looking for the [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) special name.

Comment: that was realy stupid of me,  i didnt call the parent constructor 
after i did      parent::__construct(); it fixed the error